# program not quitting when a ConnectionError happens but just freezes when an error happens

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, python-requests

**I have this fully working code** to download something. I want the code to exit when there is no Internet. Please look at the code:

```
for i in range(start, start+end):
    if count%250==0:
        print(f"Total {total_images_already+count} images downloaded in directory. {end-count} remaining from the current defined\n")

    url = df.iloc[i,ind]
    try:
        load_save_image_from_url(url,DIR,str(i))
        count+=1

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        sys.exit("Forced exit prompted by User: Quitting....")

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        sys.exit("Unable to connect to URL for some reason. So, to avoid conflicts in future, Quitting... ")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error at index {i}: {e}\n")
        pass
```

It is working exactly to my needs except, when I turn off the connection, the code just freeze. It does not show anything. I have tried using `except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e: print(e)`. No response comes out of this one too. What am I doing wrong here and what should be done?

Comment: ...sounds like you cut the connection while your program is waiting for a response...did you check your timeout settings? maybe you can reduce them?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like so.  I don't know about the Timeout settings and all. Would you please give me a hint?

Comment: could you pls provide a minimal example to reproduce the issue you are experiencing? the code above, doesn't show the most essential part: ```load_save_image_from_url```...